# Sort sentences based on the Nth word

Tags: java

I have to read a file with one sentence on each line.
Then I have to sort these sentences based on the N<sup>th</sup> word (I am given a number as an input parameter which represents the place of the *sort-by-this* word in the sentence).

File reading is done and I have loaded the words in a two-dimensional string array.

```
for(String line : Files.readAllLines(file))
for(String word : line.trim().split(" "))
```

How should I sort the sentences?

Comment: You should specify what to do if one of the lines (sentences) to compare has fewer than n words in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom `Comparator<String>`, to parametrize your `sort` invocation (invoked on either a `Collection` or an `Array`, through the `Collections` or `Arrays` utility classes respectively).

- You will need to have an instance field in your `Comparator`, that will represent the `Nth` word's index you base your sorting on, and a setter or constructor to set it
- In your `compare(String s1, String s2)` override, you will use that field to check whether both `String`s are long enough and have enough actual words (then, also decide what to do if either doesn't qualify)
- If both `String`s qualify, you will pick those words by itemizing them through a `Scanner` or `Pattern`, and return the computation of `compare` on those two words, instead of the whole `String`s
- That will guarantee that given a list of `String`s and a word index, all `String`s qualifying to have a separable word at that given word index will be compared based on the lexicographical comparison of those words, and a separate logic for those `String`s that do not qualify